# Need to get the absolute path value in perl

Tags: perl

I am storing the value of a symlink in a variable using below command:

```
$var = readlink '/home/test1/test2/test3/latest.lnx'
```

but as latest.lnx is pointing to /home/test1/test2/test3/01.02-abc, when I am trying to do

```
symlink($var,link)
```

it is creating the below result:

```
link -> /home/test1/test2/test3/01.02-abc
```

but I want the result to as below:

```
link -> 01.02-abc
```

Can someone please let me know how can I do that. Thanks

Comment: `'/home/test1/test2/test3/latest.lnx' ` where it is coming in `01.02-abc`

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am not clear. Can you please let me know the exact command I can use.

Comment: But if link were to `01.02-abc` that would be incorrect (need full path).  Can you explain what you mean by wanting a link to be like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract filename from full path with [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Basename;
my $path='/home/test1/test2/test3/01.02-abc';
my $fname = basename($path);
print "$fname";
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking to do is convert the target of the original linked path into a path that's relative to the original link.

```
use Path::Tiny qw( path );

my $orig_link = '/home/test1/test2/test3/latest.lnx';

defined( my $target = readlink($orig_link) )
   or die("Can't read link \"$orig_link\": $!\n");

$target = $target = path($target)->relative( path($orig_link)->parent );
```

Then use `$target` when creating your new link.